# How to add image and text in motion in java jFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, custom-painting

I have similar a marquee to the tags html5, text moving horizontally from right to left, works perfectly without errors.

```
public class texscroll extends JPanel {
    private int x = 510, y = 25;
    private String string = "Text in moving similary to the tags HTML5 Marquesina (<marquee>).";

    public texscroll() {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN, 15);
        setFont(font);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        setOpaque(false);
        Timer timer = new Timer(14, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                x -= 1;
                if (x == -10 * string.length()) {
                    x = 510;
                }
                repaint();
            }            
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(720, 480);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawString(string, x, y);
    }        
}
```

But now I would like to be able to add or combine text and images in movement.

```
private String string = "Text in moving similary to the tags HTML5 Marquesina (<marquee>).";
```

How can I call the images `(img/img.png)` so they can be visualized in motion?

Comment: See the 6 variants of `drawImage(..)` that a `Graphics` instance offers, or either of the variants offered by `Graphics2D`.

Comment: Check out the [Marquee Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/). It allows you to scroll components, so that component could be a JLabel with text and/or Icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply draw the image as you draw text :

```
class Texscroll extends JPanel {

    private int x = 510, y = 25;
    private final String string = "Text in moving similary to the tags HTML5 Marquesina (<marquee>).";
    private final Image image;

    public Texscroll() {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN, 15);
        setFont(font);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        image = getImage();
        Timer timer = new Timer(14, arg0 -> {
            x -= 1;
            if (x == -10 * string.length()) {
                x = 510;
            }
            repaint();
        });
        timer.start();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 480));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawString(string, x, y);
        g2.drawImage(image, x, y + 100, getFocusCycleRootAncestor());
    }

    //use any image
    private BufferedImage getImage() {
        int iconWidth =100;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(iconWidth , iconWidth,
                                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillOval(1, 1, iconWidth - 2, iconWidth - 2);
        g2.dispose();
        return img;
    }
}
```